# Need a lightweight, standalone web server for Django

Tags: django

I have a Django web application which should be easy to install on Linux systems. The app does not need much performance. It is just a simple web GUI for some services. So a full-blown deployment with Apache is not needed. I am looking for a lightweight web server that has little or no configuration; just like the Django development server.

It should be possible to run it as daemon, though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/283759/lightweight-web-server-for-django-with-small-workloads

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Quick and dirty multi-threaded Django dev server](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201103/quick_and_dirty_multithreaded_django_dev_server.html).

But, configuring apache or fastcgi to server django applications is not a hard thing, so you should really do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Green Unicorn with nginx, very light weight and fast. It does has some configuration unfortunately, so it might not be ideal for you, but worth checking out.

http://gunicorn.org

http://wiki.nginx.org/

Here is a blog post that explains how to set it up with supervisord.

http://kencochrane.net/blog/2011/06/django-gunicorn-nginx-supervisord-fabric-centos55/

Comment: gunicorn looks promising. it is absolutely easy to deploy even for people who don't have a unix background. however, it can't serve static media, so nginx (or any other webserver) is still needed. would be my choice otherwise